# What c++ compiler does when passing arguments to a function in this example?

Tags: c++

I am from C background and just trying to understand the c++ compiler behaviour in the following code sample.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class A {
       int _n;
       friend void func(const A& i1, const A& i2 = A());
   public:
     A() : _n(0) {
        cout << "default constructor: _n  " << _n << endl;
     }
     A(int n): _n(n) {
        cout << "constructor: _n  " << _n << endl;
     }
     A(const A& a):_n(a._n) {
        cout << "copy constructor: _n  " << _n << endl;
     }
     A& operator =(const A& a) {
        _n = a._n;
        cout << "assignment operator: -n  " << _n << endl;
        return *this;
     }
     ~A() {}
 };

 void func(const A& i1, const A& i2 ) {
    cout << "value i1._n " << i1._n <<endl;
    cout << "value i2._n " << i2._n <<endl;
 }

 int main( void ) {
    A a(9), b, c;

    func(10);               /* case 1 */
    func(a, A(20));         /* case 2 */
    func(A(c));             /* case 3 */
    b = a;                  /* case 4 */
 }
```

Declared func as friend of class A to access private data (_n).

case 1: I dont really understand how 10 gets assigned to _n as the value 
         expected in the first argument of func is an object reference. 
         Can someone help me how this is actually working with some example.

case 2: As the compiler evaluates from right to left, 
         a) It calls the constructor (secord argument) and assigns 20 to _n. 
         b) As the object 'a' is already constructed, it just assigns a to i1.

case 3: a) It calls the default constructor for i2. 
         b) It calls copy constructor for c and assigns to i1.

case 4: calls the assignment operator of class A.

I stepped into the code with Eclipse IDE but still can't come to a conclusive answer.

Plz accept my apologies if I made any mistakes in explaining things as this is my first
 post but will improve subsequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- case 1: I dont really understand how 10 gets assigned to _n as the value expected in the first argument of func is an object reference. Can someone help me how this is actually working with some example.

First argument is `const reference`, which will be bound to temporary constructed by `A(int)` with arg `10`. Compiler attempts to convert argument types passed to argument types expected, either by constructor or cast operator. If such constructor or cast operator exists and not marked `explicit`, a temporary will be constructed and passed as argument.

- case 2: As the compiler evaluates from right to left, a) It calls the constructor (secord argument) and assigns 20 to _n. b) As the object 'a' is already constructed, it just assigns a to i1.

Who said compiler evaluates from right to left in function arguments?! Order is undefined.

Also, it does not assign `a` to `i1`, it passes constant reference (address of) `a`.

- case 3: a) It calls the default constructor for i2. b) It calls copy constructor for c and assigns to i1.

Correct, with respect to remark above about assignment.

- case 4: calls the assignment operator of class A.

Correct.

Comment: @nyrl Thanks for the explanation. Yes, the compiler works on sequence point in determining the order of execution of expressions 
 in a sequence and each compiler defines the sequence point differently and so it's undefined.

Comment: One more thing what I saw was with another case "func(A(10))";           
it is the explicit way of invoking the constructor for A but case 1 won't work if we declare the single-parameter constructor "explicit" and thereby inhibiting the compiler to do any "implicit" conversion 
as you mentioned and eventually I get the following error:
`test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 test.cpp:49: error: invalid initialization of reference of type    ‘const A&’ from expression of type ‘int’
 test.cpp:39: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void func(const A&, const A&)’`

Comment: @user3088983 Actually, sequence point is something defined by standard, so compiler must follow it. Comma as arguments delimiter is not a sequence point. Operator comma is.